# Correct bash sed command syntax to get a correct substring

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

Trying to get a sub-string from a:

> foo-bar-8568887b6f-d95wk        1/1     Running            0          48m

to get a:
`foo-bar-8568887b6f-d95wk`

using:
`sed 's/^.\((foo-bar)[^\s]+\).*$/\1/'`

However that would return the whole string:
`foo-bar-8568887b6f-d95wk        1/1     Running            0          48m`

What is the correct sed command in this case?

Comment: `[^\s]` matches any char but ``\`` and `s`, you need `[^[:space:]]*` or `[^[:space:]]\{1,\}` instead. Also, your string does not contain `ncc-full-druid-broker`

Comment: The goal is to get substring between `foo-bar` and the first empty space.

Comment: Here you may just use `awk '$0 ~ /^foo-bar/{print $1}'` or `sed -n 's/^.*\(foo-bar[^[:space:]]*\).*$/\1/p'`

Comment: Ok, this can be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Why not just `awk '{print $1}'`? If you need more than that then [edit] your question to provide a more realistic example.

Comment: Why not use `cut` for this purpose if you read from a file? The command should be `cut -d ' ' -f1` -- magic here, cut was designed for tasks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- `.` after `^` requires a single character to be present
- `(foo-bar)` in the POSIX BRE pattern matches `(foo-bar)` but there are no parentheses in your string
- `[^\s]` in a POSIX bracket expression matches a char other than `\` and `s`, not a non-whitespace char
- `+` in the POSIX BRE pattern matches a `+` char.

Use

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(foo-bar[^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Here,

- `-n`  - suppresses the default line output
- `s` - substitution command
- `/^.*\(foo-bar[^[:space:]]*\).*`/`- matches start of the string, any 0+ chars, captures`foo-bar`and 0 or more chars other than whitespace into Group 1 (`\1`), and then matches the rest of the string
- `\1` - replaces the whole match with Group 1  contents
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Alternatively, consider an `awk` command that will work if the match is always expected at the start of the string:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^foo-bar/{print $1}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wpR2vW). It means that if the line starts with `foo-bar` (`$0 ~ /^foo-bar/`) `awk` will print Field 1 (the default field separator is whitespace, so you will get the substring from the start till the first whitespace).

Comment: also very few seds would recognize `\s` as shorthand for `[[:space:]]` (maybe just GNU sed) and if they did then the opposite would be `\S`, not `[^\s]`. You don't need `$0 ~` in the awk command btw.